# Не запускается OpenVPN на Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

настраивал **OpenVPN** сервер.
Делал по примеру от сюда: https://blog.yodo.im/openvpn-na-ubuntu/?unapproved=952&moderation-hash=4708eb9bcbe842c633ad15bc561fec29#comment-952

На этапе запуска, выдает ошибку:

```
openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-07-19 20:35:02 UTC; 3s ago
       Docs: man:openvpn(8)
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
    Process: 13303 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --c>
   Main PID: 13303 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Pre-connection initialization successful"

Jul 19 20:35:02 VPS systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 19 20:35:02 VPS systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Может это связано с путями сертификатов и ключей в `server.conf` или какие еще могут быть варианты?

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Ниже логи, закоментировал проблемную строку

```
Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383259 Current Parameter Settings: 

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383325   config = '/etc/openvpn/server.conf'

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383335   mode = 1

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383343   persist_config = DISABLED

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383351   persist_mode = 1

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383359   show_ciphers = DISABLED

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383367   show_digests = DISABLED

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383374   show_engines = DISABLED

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383382   genkey = DISABLED

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383390   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383398   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383406   connect_retry_max = 0

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383413 Connection profiles [0]:

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383423   proto = udp

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383430   local = '192.168.1.223'

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383438   local_port = '2003'

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383446   remote = '[UNDEF]'

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383455   remote_port = '2003'

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383463   remote_float = DISABLED

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383470   bind_defined = DISABLED

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383478 NOTE: --mute triggered...

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383493 267 variation(s) on previous 20 message(s) suppressed by --mute

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383501 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)]
 [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=383521 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020, LZO 2.10

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=386989 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=387435 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=387459 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=387473 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1184 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=387597 ROUTE_GATEWAY 128.199.32.1/255.255.224.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=ba:5c:6a:b5:a4:91

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=400576 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=400927 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=400964 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=400984 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=422455 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.11.12.1 peer 10.11.12.2

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=429267 /sbin/ip route add 10.11.12.0/24 via 10.11.12.2

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=433408 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1450 EF:121 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=433462 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=433493 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]

> Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=433519 TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on
> local address [AF_INET]192.168.1.223:2003: Cannot assign requested
> address (errno=99)

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=433532 Exiting due to fatal error

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=433557 /sbin/ip route del 10.11.12.0/24

Wed Jul 20 11:00:28 2022 us=441053 Closing TUN/TAP interface
```

Добавляю также конфиг server.conf

```
local 192.168.1.223
port 2003
proto udp
dev tun
ca /opt/ovpn/keys/pki/ca.crt
cert /opt/ovpn/keys/pki/issued/server.crt
key /opt/ovpn/keys/pki/private/server.key
dh /opt/ovpn/keys/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /opt/ovpn/keys/pki/ta.key
server 10.11.12.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 360
max-clients 10
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 4
mute 20
daemon
```

Comment: Ну, а в логах что пишет? Если для себя поднимаете, то советую WireGuard, его горааааздо легче поднимать, не нужна вся возня с сертификатами.

Comment: Логи добавил заметил это Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET]192.168.1.223:2003: Cannot assign requested address (errno=99)

Comment: Есть готовых много скриптов для быстрой установки в один клик, например `wget https://git.io/vpn -O openvpn-install.sh` (после установить право скрипту на запуск и запустить его)

Comment: Да, есть. Но хотелось бы самому в ручную сделать все, так сказать решить вопрос, та посмотреть что и как вообще

Comment: Если cannot assign, то логичный вопрос — IP-адрес 192.168.1.223 назначен хоть на какой-нибудь сетевой интерфейс в системе?

Comment: Поменял в этой строке на "local 192.168.1.223" на белый ip сервака. Все нормально стартануло и работает